# error: undefined method 'link_to_remote'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RJS, I follow the short example in [this guide](http://www.codyfauser.com/2005/11/20/rails-rjs-templates)

I'm including all the default javascript library in the application.html.erb

when I fire up the server and check the page, I got a error:

```
Showing /Users/PowerBook/Desktop/makprojects/drummercymbal/app/views/videos/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `link_to_remote' for #<#<Class:0x217f64>:0x213d74>
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:   <li>Cat</li>
7:   <li>Mouse</li>
8: </ul>
9: <%= link_to_remote("Add a fox", :url => { :action => :add}) %>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using rails 3.x.x, than there is no `link_to_remote`, there is `link_to 'Add a fox', { :action => :add}, :remote => true`

Comment: Tig thanks for your quick rely, your solution is right. But then I got anther error No route matches {:action=>"add", :controller=>"videos"}, I'm wandering if there is simple rails 3.0 rjs example that can let me study?

Comment: Wow, the Rails docs are _seriously_ out of date. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html#the-quintessential-ajax-rails-helper-link_to_remote is still the top Google hit for "rails ajax"